# SharePoint Search Errors - On Gantt Charts

Tags: search

My search crawl errors out on a gantt chart web part in our team sites.

The error message is **The SharePoint item being crawled returned an error when attempting to download the item.**

I have verified that my search user account can login to the page and see the content.

Any ideas?

Comment: check the crawl log for further info. Also check if ULS log has some relevant info and add to post

Comment: that was from the crawl log.

https://portal.inghamisd.org/projects/prc-10th-grade-presentations-and-visits/lists/project tasks/gantt.aspx  
The SharePoint item being crawled returned an error when attempting to download the item.

Comment: I can click on the error and open it with my search user account

Comment: i found the uls viewer on msdn, what should i search for?

Comment: Anything related to search with status high or "worse"

Comment: I found this similar thread on MSDN http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sharepoint2010general/thread/f5bebbf9-028d-4c0a-bee6-3e5d0755c08c

Comment: It's specifically related to the gantt chart web part, if switch it to a list view, then it clears up the problem

Comment: When i search the crawl logs, I'm not certain how to search on "high" or "worse"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.benstegink.com/sharepoint-2010-search-gantt-chart-bug/

You should be able to create a generic search rule using wild cards in your search administration to exclude them all. Creating a rules to exclude *://*gantt.aspx should exclude all gantt.aspx pages from your search.

I used this and the crawl worked fine.